# Insertion sort - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I am trying to implement insertion sort using the min() function on python. It works for most of the cases however when I plug in the value of 0 more than once the entire thing breaks down. The code is as following :

```
def sortArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        # Selection sort 
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            temp = nums[i]
            index = nums.index((min(nums[i:])))
            print(f"val = {nums[index]} nums[{i}:]")
            nums[i] = min(nums[i:])
            nums[index] = temp
            print(f"Step : {i} -- {nums}")
        return nums
```

For a test case [-100, 0, 0, -1, -4, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, -19] I receive following output:

```
val = -100 nums[0:]
Step : 0 -- [-100, 0, 0, -1, -4, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, -19]
val = -19 nums[1:]
Step : 1 -- [-100, -19, 0, -1, -4, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, 0]
val = -4 nums[2:]
Step : 2 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, 0]
val = -1 nums[3:]
Step : 3 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, 0]
val = 0 nums[4:]
Step : 4 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, 0]
val = 0 nums[5:]
Step : 5 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, 0]
val = 0 nums[6:]
Step : 6 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 200, 0, 0, 30, 4000, 32, 0]
val = 0 nums[7:]
Step : 7 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 200, 30, 0, 0, 4000, 32, 0]
val = 0 nums[8:]
Step : 8 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 200, 30, 4000, 0, 0, 32, 0]
val = 0 nums[9:]
Step : 9 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 200, 30, 4000, 32, 0, 0, 0]
val = 0 nums[10:]
Step : 10 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 200, 30, 4000, 32, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have duplicated zeros. At index six the min is 0. When you lookup the value zero in the entire array it picks the first zero and replace it with 200. This is the edit that makes your code to work:

```
def sortArray(self, nums) -> list[int]:
        # Insertion sort 
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            temp = nums[i]
            index = nums[i:].index((min(nums[i:])))
            print(f"val = {nums[i+index]} nums[{i}:]")
            nums[i] = min(nums[i:])
            nums[i+index] = temp
            print(f"Step : {i} -- {nums}")
        return nums
```

This is the output:

```
val = -100 nums[0:]
Step : 0 -- [-100, 0, 0, -1, -4, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, -19]
val = -19 nums[1:]
Step : 1 -- [-100, -19, 0, -1, -4, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, 0]
val = -4 nums[2:]
Step : 2 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, 0]
val = -1 nums[3:]
Step : 3 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, 0]
val = 0 nums[4:]
Step : 4 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, 0]
val = 0 nums[5:]
Step : 5 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 200, 30, 4000, 32, 0]
val = 0 nums[6:]
Step : 6 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 0, 30, 4000, 32, 200]
val = 30 nums[7:]
Step : 7 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 0, 30, 4000, 32, 200]
val = 32 nums[8:]
Step : 8 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 0, 30, 32, 4000, 200]
val = 200 nums[9:]
Step : 9 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 0, 30, 32, 200, 4000]
val = 4000 nums[10:]
Step : 10 -- [-100, -19, -4, -1, 0, 0, 0, 30, 32, 200, 4000]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am very new with programming. How did adding i solve the issue?

Comment: I have changed this line ```index = nums.index((min(nums[i:])))```  to ```index = nums[i:].index((min(nums[i:])))``` in order to search only in the portion of ```nums``` that have not been seen before. Then ```index``` is valid in ```nums[i:]```. In order to swap values in ```nums``` array we need to add ```i``` to ```index```